# Determinant of $T(f(t)) = f(-t)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Find the determinant of the linear transformation:

$T(f(t)) = f(-t)$, where $T: {\cal P}_3 \to {\cal P}_3$.

I know how to calculate the determinant, but I am having trouble setting up the matrix. I think I have to use the standard basis for ${\cal P}_3$, $\{1,t,t^2,t^3\}$.

Answer (score 4):

You compute $T$ in each of these guys, write the result in the basis, and put the coordinates in the columns of a matrix. For example, $T(1) = 1$ and $T(t) = -t$, so: $$ [T] = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \ast & \ast \\ 0 & -1 & \ast & \ast \\ 0 & 0  & \ast & \ast \\ 0 & 0 & \ast &\ast\end{bmatrix}. $$Can you fill in the gaps and compute the determinant of the above matrix?

Answer (score 3):

Let $e_1 = 1, e_2=t, e_3=t^2, e_4=t^3$, then we just use the definition $$T(I) = \det(T)I$$ where $I=e_1\wedge e_2 \wedge e_3 \wedge e_4$.

Firstly $$\begin{cases}T(e_1) = 1 = e_1 \\ T(e_2) = -t = -e_2 \\ T(e_3) = (-t)^2 = t^2 = e_3 \\ T(e_4) = (-t)^3 = -t^3 = -e_4\end{cases}$$

Then $$\begin{align} T(I) &= T(e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_3 \wedge e_4) \\ &= T(e_1)\wedge T(e_2)\wedge T(e_3)\wedge T(e_4) \\ &= e_1 \wedge (-e_2) \wedge e_3 \wedge (-e_4) \\ &= --e_1\wedge e_2 \wedge e_3 \wedge e_4 \\ &= e_1\wedge e_2 \wedge e_3 \wedge e_4 \\ &= I\end{align}$$

Thus the determinant of $T$ is?

Comment: Using $\wedge$ was unexpected. I liked it. +1

Answer (score 1):

You're right:
$$T(1) = 1 $$
$$T(t) = -t$$
$$T(t^2) = t^2$$
$$T(t^3) = -t^3$$

So the matrix which represent the transformation is
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}\right)
$$
and the determinant is 1